# Iterative fine-tuning of the embedding models

Tags: algorithm, embedding, word-embedding, large-language-model, llama-index

**Context:**

I learned that to improve the search results of the RAG based approach, we can finetune the open source embedding models.

Now I have one `pdf` file (my private dataset) using which I will create the train/eval dataset, finetune my embedding model, and store the embeddings into a vector DB. Suppose `n` embeddings were stored into the DB.

**Question:**

Now tommorrow, a **new** `pdf` file comes to me.

1. Then should I re-finetune the earlier finetuned embedding model?
2. Because this re-finetuned model will now generate slightly different embeddings, will the earlier `n` embeddings stored in my DB get outdated? Will I have to delete them?
3. So now, if there are `m` **new** embeddings from the second `pdf` file to be stored, will I have to store a total of (`n + m`) new embeddings into the DB?

So as the new data comes up, this problem will become a squared order problem as far as complexity is considered.